# MRTK increasing pointer extent

Tags: hololens, mrtk

I'm trying to extend the maximum depth of the pointers to use in a scene where objects can be further away. I've set the 'pointing extent' setting under the MixedRealityPointerProfile which seems to have no effect.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: How do you set the value? The pointing extent default value is 10. You said it has no effect. Do you mean it still uses the default value after you change the setting?

Answer (score 0):

Take [the official HandTracking project](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/main/Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/HandTracking) as an example. To increase the pointer extent in Unity, please check the following steps.

- In MRTK component, navigate to [Input] -> [Pointers] -> [pointer extent], setting the global maximum extent value.
  [image]
- Then navigate to [Input] -> [Pointers] -> [pointer options] -> [ShellHandRayPointer] and edit this prefab. In ShellHandRayPointer script, change the value of “Pointer Extent” and “Default Pointer Extent”.
  [image]

If you cannot alter the prefab in package folder, you need to drag it into your self’s Asset folder then select this prefab in MRTK component.

Basic idea is besides changing the global extent value in MRTK, you also need to customize the Pointer profile to make it work. The above steps will modify the hand tracking pointer in HoloLens, and feel free to modify other pointer profiles if necessary.

To be clear, in the common scenario, interacting long distant objects are not recommended because due to small view angle, distant objects have to be extreme large for interactive. It is also recommended to check the document on [Sizing recommendations - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/interactable-object#sizing-recommendations)